# Response Status of One-Time Action

Tags: rest

If I have a resource that can only be modified **once** via a PATCH command, and if subsequent PATCH requests were to be made to it, would it be best to:

- simply return the current resource's representation (essentially a GET on it), or
- return a 400 or 422 status, or
- something else?

Comment: 405 Method Not Allowed comes to mind

Comment: @TimCastelijns, that's a good point. I forgot about 405 - I was only using it for the verbs that I won't support, but I guess it makes sense in this context, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely want a **4xx** response for this.

Took a quick look at the RFC list at http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html and this one was the one I think best suits your situation

> **405 Method Not Allowed**
>
> The method specified in the Request-Line is not allowed for the
>   resource identified by the Request-URI. The response MUST include an
>   Allow header containing a list of valid methods for the requested
>   resource.

The name of the status *Method not allowed* perfectly matches what you want to return, I think.

---

I do not think you should use

> **400 Bad Request**
>
> The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed
>   syntax.

because there is no case of a malformed syntax, i.e. the request is valid.

Same goes for

> **422 Unprocessable Entity**
>
> The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to
>   semantic errors.

this is also not the case.

> simply return the current resource's representation (essentially a GET
>   on it)

What status code did you plan on sending with it? **200 OK** like a GET usually does? I think it's quite easy to shove this one off the table considering the request was not OK, i.e. it did not do what the user expected/wanted it to do ;-)

---

An alternative to the **405** I mentioned earlier could be

> **403 Forbidden**
>
> The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated

but I think **405** fits the situation better.